# DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-551, SQLSTATE=42501

Tags: java, db2, db2-luw

I try to run a query on db2 but I get the following error :

```
 DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-551, SQLSTATE=42501, SQLERRMC=GCD_ADMIN;SELECT;GCD_ADMIN.TAYEBEDS, DRIVER=4.7.85
```

this is my code :

```
 results = stmt.executeQuery("select "+schema +"."+ edsTable + ".OBJECTTYPE from "+ schema +"."+ edsTable);
```

Comment: It may be a problem of missing privileges for the current user, see here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1588687/db2-connection-problem-with-java

Comment: how can i add privilege with DB2 CLP for this user ?

Comment: db2 grant dataaccess on database to user <username>

Comment: `db2 grant select on GCD_ADMIN.TAYEBEDS to user GCD_ADMIN;`

Comment: make a var and log your command.  Then execute the command.  You might need to just trim up the variables in your sql statement.